# Insertar datos en una tabla desde php con PDO

Tags: php

Veo muchos tutoriales antiguos que no utilizan PDO. Estoy intentando insertar pero, no lo he conseguido. El código es este:

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();

$title = 'Home';
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="First Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" required placeholder="Last Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="number" name="age" required placeholder="Age" min="10" > </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert"></input></td>
</tr>
';

$content .=  '</table>';
// get values form input text and number
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    // mysql query to insert data
    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (:fname,:lname,:age)";
    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":fname"=>$fname,":lname"=>$lname,":age"=>$age));
        // check if mysql insert query successful
    if($pdoExec)
    {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }else{
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }

include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Me dan errores del siguiente tipo:

> Notice: Undefined index: lname in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 35

Estoy un poco desconcertado ya que seguí todos los pasos exactos como para que me de error.

Comment: Deberias mostrar el código tanto del form, como deldatabase.php para ver el error

Answer (score 3):

No veo que estés incluyendo la etiqueta respectiva para delimitar el formulario:

```
<form method="POST">
    Inputs aquí ....
</form>
```

Por favor consulta la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: aun asi obtengo los mismos errores basicamente lo que intento es crear un formulario para introducir datos en mi base de datos en PDO

Answer (score 1):

Luego de haber agregado las tags de form, después de `$content .=  '</table>';`, agrega:

```
if(!empty($_POST){
```

y cierra la condición

```
    }else{
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }

}  // <--- después del else
```

Comment: `$_POST` puede estar definida, pero eso no significa que `$_POST['lname']` haya sido seteado.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer debes realizar una verificación para asegurarte de que el código PHP que tienes únicamente se ejecute luego de enviar el formulario. Para esto, puedes poner lo siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST["insert"])) {

    //tu codigo aca...

}
```

Además, debes envolver el formulario en etiquetas "form" de la siguiente manera:

```
<form method="POST">

    <!-- tu formulario aca -->

</form>
```

Es verdad, hay bastantes tutos antiguos en la red que no explican con PDO sus ejemplos. Sin embargo, puedes guiarte de este tuto que he encontrado en el cual justamente dan ejemplos prácticos con conexión PDO desde PHP/MySQL:

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/conectar-php-con-mysql/

Vas a poder ver que dan un ejemplo con mysqli y luego con PDO a modo de comparativa.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, intenta utilizando  este código, creo que el error que tienes es porque no estas vinculando los valores que vas a insertar eso se hace con el metodo bindParam().

```
try {
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];

  $sql= "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (:fname,:lname,:age)";

  $sentencia = $pdoConnect -> prepare($sql);
  $sentencia-> bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sentencia -> bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sentencia -> bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $pdoExec = $sentencia -> execute(); 

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     print 'ERROR: '. $e->getMessage();
     print '<br/>Data Not Inserted';
}
if($pdoExec)
{
    echo 'Data Inserted';
}
```